# OOP Python: Trying to create Binary Search Tree, gets 'attributeError' obeject gets perverted

Tags: python, oop, binary-search-tree, attributeerror

I am trying to create a Randomized Binary Search Tree. I am following the instructions (pseudo code) on this [web page](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-python/7_2_Treap_Randomized_Binary.html). Also I am doing this with TEAP (Tree Heap) technique of given the elements different priorities and thus making a balanced Binary Search Tree.

The code is what follows:

```
import random

class TreapNode:
    """Skapar en nod för det randomiserade binära sökträdet"""

def __init__(self, value = None, parent = None, left_child = None, right_child = None):
    self.val = value
    self.pri = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
    self.par = parent
    self.left = left_child
    self.right = right_child

def addParent(self, p):
    """Tilldelar noden en förälder"""
    self.par = p

def addLeft(self, lc):
    """Tilldelar noden ett barn till vänster"""
    self.left = lc

def addRight(self, rc):
    """Tilldelar noden ett barn till höger"""
    self.right = rc

def addValue(self, val):
    """Tilldelar noden ett värde, en s.k. adress"""
    self.val = val

def getParent(self):
    """Returnerar nodens förälder"""
    return self.par

def getLeft(self):
    """Returnerar nodens vänstra barn"""
    return self.left

def getRight(self):
    """Returnerar nodens högra barn"""
    return self.right

def getValue(self):
    """Returnerar nodens värde/adress"""
    return self.val

def getPriority(self):
    """Returnerar nodens prioritet"""
    return self.pri

class BalancedBinaryTree:
    """Skapar ett tomt binärt sökträd som är välbalanserat"""

def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.size = 0
    self.string = []

def rotate_left(self, u): # privat
    """Byter plats på noden u och dess högra barn genom rotation""" #denna algoritm bevarar 
    w = u.getRight()                                                #"binära-sökträds" egenskapen
    w.addParent(u.getParent)                                        #hos varje nod
    if w.getParent() != None:
        p = w.getParent()
        if p.getLeft() == u:
            w.getParent().addLeft(w)
        else:
            w.getParent().addRight(w)
    u.addRight(w.getLeft())
    if u.getRight() != None:
        u.getRight().addParent(u)
    u.addParent(w)
    w.addLeft(u)
    if w.getParent() == None:
        self.root = w


def rotate_right(self, u): # privat
    """Byter plats på noden u och dess vänstra barn genom rotation""" #denna algoritm bevarar
    w = u.getLeft()                                                   #"binära-sökträds" egenskapen
    w.addParent(u.getParent())                                        #hos varje nod
    if w.getParent() != None:
        if w.getParent().getLeft() == u:
            w.getParent().addLeft(w)
        else:
            w.getParent().addRight(w)
    u.addLeft(w.getRight())
    if u.getLeft() != None:
        u.getLeft().addParent(u)
    u.addParent(w)
    w.addRight(u)
    if w.getParent() == None:
        self.root = w

def add(self, val):
    """Låter användaren lägga till ett värde, men bara om det inte redan finns"""
    u = TreapNode(value = val)
    if self.add_node(val, u):
        self.bubble_up(u)
        self.size += 1
        self.string.append(val)
        return True
    return False

def bubble_up(self, u): # prviat
    """Om prioriteten hos u är lägre än dess förälder, så byter u och föräldern plats"""

    while u.getParent() != None and u.getParent().getPriority() > u.getPriority():
        if u.getParent().getRight() == u:
            self.rotate_left(u.getParent())
        else:
            self.rotate_right(u.getParent())
    if u.getParent() == None:
        self.root = u


def findString(self, val):
    """Låter användaren söka efter specifika värden. Returnerar värdet om det finns, annars None"""
    w = self.root
    while w != None:
        if val < w.getValue():
            w = w.getLeft()
        elif val > w.getValue():
            w = w.getRight()
        else:
            return w.getValue()
    return None


def add_node(self, val, node): # privat
    """Tilldelar ett löv ett barn med värdet val""" # här bryts inte "binär-
    p = self.find_last(val)                              # sökträds" regeln
    return self.add_child(p, node)

def find_last(self, val): #privat
    """Finner lämplig nod som kan tilldelas ett barn till höger/vänster med värdet val"""
    w = self.root
    prev = None
    #if w != None:
    #    print(w.getValue())
    #else:
    #    print(w)
    while w != None:
        prev = w
        if val < w.getValue():
            w = w.getLeft()
        elif val > w.getValue():
            w = w.getRight()
        else:
            return w
    return prev

def add_child(self, p, u): #privat
    """Tilldelar en nod p ett barn u till höger/vänster"""
    if p == None:
        self.root = u
    else:
        if u.getValue() < p.getValue():
            p.addLeft(u)
            u.addParent(p)
        elif u.getValue() > p.getValue():
            p.addRight(u)
            u.addParent(p)
        else:
            print(u.getValue())
            print(p.getValue())
            return False
    return True

def getSize(self):
    return self.size

def orderedString(self):
    if self.size == 0:
        msg = "[]"
        return msg
    else:
        orderedlist = sorted(self.string)
return orderedlist

def main():
# Testkod till TreapNode() klassen
nod = TreapNode()
nod.addParent(TreapNode(value = "abc", left_child = nod))
assert nod.getParent().getValue() == "abc"
assert nod.getParent().getLeft() == nod
assert -1000 <= nod.getPriority() <= 1000

nod.addRight(TreapNode(value=10, parent=nod))
nod.addValue("abcd")
assert nod.getRight().getValue() == 10
assert nod.getValue() == "abcd"

# Testkod till BalancedBinaryTree
tree = BalancedBinaryTree()
assert tree.orderedString() == "[]"
assert tree.getSize() == 0
assert tree.findString("abc") == None

tree.add("abc")
tree.add("aaa")
tree.add("bbb")
assert tree.orderedString() == ['aaa', 'abc', 'bbb']
assert tree.getSize() == 3

tree.add("hej")
tree.add("min")
tree.add("van")
tree.add("pa")
tree.add("andra")
tree.add("sidan")
tree.add("jorden")
tree.add("omg")
tree.add("lol")
tree.add("sos")
assert tree.orderedString() == ['aaa', 'abc', 'andra', 'bbb', 'hej', 'jorden', 'min', 'pa', 'sidan', 'van']
assert tree.getSize() == 10
tree.add("hej") # finns redan i trädet
assert tree.getSize() == 10 # alltså finns ingen dublett

assert tree.findString("hej") == "hej"
assert tree.findString("jorden") == "jorden"
assert tree.findString("sos") == "sos"
assert tree.findString("aldrig") == None
assert tree.findString("nagonsin") == None

# Tidskomplexitet för alla operationer:
#
# add() = O(nlog(n)) där n är antalet element
# findString() = O(log(n))
# getSize() = O(1)
# orderedString() = O(n), eftersom sorted() måste jämföra n element





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, when I execute this code I get an error message that says `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getLeft'`. Alright, so I check the object that is passed to the function, and this seems to happen:

The element, that is the nodeobject, is passed, eventually, to the `rotate_left(self,u)` method. Here the parameter `u` is the nodeobject. I "reach" inside within this nodeobject to get its leftchild. Then in turn I 'reach' within this object back to the Nodeobject, leftchildobjects so called parent. Now things get mixed up: The Parentobject is perverted in some way. It should be identical to the Nodeobject, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong. If I print the nodeobject and its leftchild and leftchildParent, you will notice the difference.

Nodeobject `<__main__.TreapNode object at 0x7fcd32c90898>`

Leftchildobject `<__main__.TreapNode object at 0x7fcd32c908d0>`

Leftchildobjects parent (this should obviously be Nodeobject above) `<bound method TreapNode.getParent of <__main__.TreapNode object at 0x7fcd32c90898>>`

What is happening in the last step?

**EDIT**

```
    def rotate_left(self, u):
    """Byter plats på noden u och dess högra barn genom rotation""" 
    p = TreapNode()
    p.addParent(u.getRight())
    p.addParent(u.getParent)
    if p.getParent() != None:
        if p.getParent().getLeft() == u:
            p.getParent().addLeft(p)
        else:
            p.getParent().addRight(p)
    u.addRight(p.getLeft())
    if u.getRight() != None:
        u.getRight().addParent(u)
    u.addParent(p)
    p.addLeft(u)
    if p.getParent() == None:
        self.root = p
```

Here is the method where something doesn't work. The if statement `if p.getParent().getLeft() == u` raises an error namely `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getLeft'`. What exactly am I supposed to do not to raise this error, it looks fine to me(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getParent` is a method, you have to call it to get the value.

```
w.addParent(u.getParent())
```

It's worth noting that the getter/setter pattern doesn't really make sense in Python, and your code would be greatly simplified without it.

EDIT:

Look at the line `p.addParent(u.getParent)`.  What's happening there is that you are assigning `u.getParent` to be the parent of `p`.  But `u.getParent` is a method.  So when you do `p.getParent().getLeft()`, that's equivalent to `u.getParent.getLeft()`, which doesn't work because that method does not have a `getLeft` method.

As to getters and setters: what makes you think you need them?  Your method could just as easily be

```
def rotate_left(self, u):
    """Byter plats på noden u och dess högra barn genom rotation""" 
    p = TreapNode()
    p.par = u.right
    p.par = u.par  # Is this what you intend to happen? 
    if p.par:  # None is falsy
        if p.par.left == u:
            p.par.left = p
        else:
            p.par.right = p
    u.right = p.left
    if u.right:
        u.right.par = u
    u.par = p
    p.left = u
    if not p.par:
        self.root = p
```

I also don't see a `__eq__` method defined in your objects.  The default `__eq__` method only returns True if the two objects are the same instance.  Since you use `==` in your code, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: I am calling it? When I run the program I get the error message `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getLeft'`. This happens on the if statement under rotateLeft() when I compare p.getLeft() == u . What o you mean by the getter/setter functions are dispensable, how else would I reach the objects' values?

Comment: Okay so I solved it using the `copy.deepcopy()` method which creates a copy of an object that can be altered without affecting the original object. But I am still curious about how getter/setter doesn't make sense in Python, if you care how to explain how else I should do it.

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer I've made an edit to try and answer your questions.  You should look into the difference between equality and identity in Python: you're expecting two objects that have the same attributes to be the same object.  It's a subtle difference, but very important.  You might also benefit from implementing a `__str__` method so you can see the changes in your objects by printing them out.  All of these "double underscore" methods can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).  Don't read that whole page, but use it as a reference.